# thread.interrupt() cause segmentation fault. boost asio c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have code, which accept users and create a thread to each, and when I try to exit the thread in connection function using thread.interrupt(), my program crashes with segmentation fault. The number "123" is printed but after it goes segmentation fault.

```
class user {
private:
    std::string name_;
    tcp::socket *socket_;
    int count_;
    boost::thread *thread_;
public:
    user(tcp::socket *socket, boost::thread *thread) {
        thread_ = thread;
        socket_ = socket;
    }
    void connection() {
        while (true) {
            std::cout << 123;
            std::cout.flush();
            thread_->interrupt();
        }
    }
};

class server {
private:
    boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

public:
    server() : io_context_(), acceptor_(io_context_, tcp::endpoint (
            address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 3030)) {
    }
    void startAccept() {
        while (true) {
            tcp::socket socket(io_context_);
            acceptor_.accept(socket);
            boost::thread *user_thread;
            user usr(&socket, user_thread);
            user_thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&user::connection,&usr));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    server serv;
    serv.startAccept();
    return 0;
}
```

I try detach() function, but it didnt help

Comment: `user usr(&socket, user_thread);` -- You are passing an uninitialized pointer `user_thread` to a function.  In C++, a function can do nothing with an uninitialized pointer that is passed to it.  In short, your issue has nothing to do with threads or boost -- it is just a misuse of pointers.

Comment: That is a horrible looking code. There is a memory leak and ASIO is an async I/O framework so that you don't have to spawn a thread per connection in the first place. With that said, what do you think happens when invoking `boost::thread::interrupt()`? It throws an exception. What happens when you don't catch an exception?

Comment: Then how can I initialize it and pass to the function?

Comment: @muerewaa -- You're asking "how can I initialize it", but it isn't clear *what* you are supposed to be doing with that pointer.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/nz9qodTbo).  That is how fundamentally broken your code attempt is -- that program uses no threads, no boost, no asio, etc.  Instead it shows the fundamental problem with your code.  If I attempted to print `*x`, in `main`, I more than likely won't see `1500` printed -- instead a random garbage number, or the program may even crash.  Try it yourself.

Comment: Then add to that, the pointer is a local variable within the `while` loop.  Each time that loop iterates, that pointer is "brand new", leaving the previous pointer dangling.

Comment: Indeed, the commenters make many good observations. In the spirit of "show, don't tell" here's correcctions [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8cd95e56a54b37e) I think it should be 3x simpler still, in particular `connection` should not be part of `user` which was creating your conflicting lifetime situation

Comment: You pass pointer to `socket` object that immediately goes out of scope into `usr` constructor leaving it with dangling pointer. Then you pass pointer to `usr` object that immediately goes out of scope into `thread` constructor leaving it with dangling pointer. Creating one thread per connection is a horrible idea anyway. You should figure out how to manage object lifetime in C++ prior to diving into advanced stuff , such as boost asio and threads.